# What is the terminal speed of a falling object subject to drag proportional to its velocity if it travels a certain distance in a given time?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, drag

This is problem 7.52 from the first volume of Alonso and Finn's *Fundamental University Physics*.

The given data is that a body falls 108 meters in five seconds. We are to find the terminal velocity if it is dropped from rest and feels a drag force proportional to its velocity.

**Work so far:**

Finding an analytical solution for this is straightforward. The equation of motion is
$$ma = mg - bv$$
where $b$ is the proportionality constant.

The acceleration is
$$a = g - \frac{b v}{m}$$
and we can write
$$\begin{align}dv &= \left(g - \frac{b v}{m}\right) dt. \\
dv &= -\frac{b}{m} \left(v - \frac{m g}{b}\right) dt. \end{align}$$

We can integrate to get an expression for the velocity.
$$\begin{align} \int_0^v \frac{dv'}{v' - \frac{m g}{b}} &= \int_0^t - \frac{b}{m} dt'. \\
\ln \left(\frac{m g - b v}{m g}\right) &= - \frac{b}{m} t. \\
m g - b v &= m g e^{- \frac{b}{m} t}. \\
v &= \frac{m g}{b} \left(1 - e^{- \frac{b}{m} t}\right). \end{align}$$

Analytically, clearly the terminal speed is $v_\mathrm{T} = \frac{m g}{b}$. I assume that since information is given about distance traveled and the time elapsed, one is meant to find a numerical answer. The above can be integrated again to find the position. Assuming I've gotten that part right, we have

$$\begin{align} x &= \frac{m g}{b} t - \frac{m}{b} \frac{mg}{b} \left(1 - e^{-\frac{b}{m} t} \right). \end{align}$$

Obviously the expression for $v$ itself appears in this expression and that is how I feel I should be able to proceed to somehow solve for $\frac{m}{b}$ or something, but I just can't see where to go from here. I can't come up with any further assumptions since I don't know anything about the body itself or how $b$ depends on its properties. I'm greatly thankful for any help on what I'm overlooking. I've been working through this text from the beginning, and I have realized it does have some pretty serious issues with errors in the odd-number solutions at the back (like the same errors reappearing frequently, for instance regarding tetrahedron geometry with questions in both chapters 3 and 4) and a few questions that seem unclear about what they are actually asking. So this may just be poorly constructed, as bold as it may sound to say so.

Comment: HINT:  Try to manipulate your expression to get rid of $m$ and $b$ (which you don't know and don't care about) in favor of $v_T$ and $g$ (which you are trying to find and already know, respectively.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem! I show here that you do not have to solve for $b$ and $m$, but for their ratio $k = b/m$ which is unique for the given set of data.

Let me just rewrite your equations

$$
\begin{aligned}
x(t) &= \frac{1}{k} g t - \frac{1}{k^2} g \bigl( 1 - e^{-kt} \bigr) \\
v(t) &= \frac{1}{k} g \bigl( 1 - e^{-kt} \bigr)
\end{aligned}
$$

You have correctly identified that velocity appears in the displacement

$$x(t) = \frac{1}{k} \bigl( g t - v(t) \bigr)$$

and the terminal velocity is

$$\boxed{v_f = g t_f - k x_f}$$

where $x_f = x(t_f)$ and $v_f = v(t_f)$. The only problem here is that value of $k$ is unknown. I am not sure if this is possible to solve analytically, but it is possible to show that there is only one solution for given $x_f$ and $t_f$

$$\underbrace{(x_f/g) k^2 - t_f k + 1}_{f_1(k)} = \underbrace{e^{-t_f k}}_{f_2(k)}$$

In the above equation the only unknown is $k$ which is determined from the intercept between quadratic function $f_1(k)$ and exponential function $f_2(k)$. There are two solutions for the above equation: (i) trivial solution is $k = 0$, and (ii) the other solution is what you need to calculate $v_f$. Bottom line is that there is only one non-trivial solution $k^\star$ to the above equation which means final velocity solution $v_f$ is unique for given $x_f$ and $t_f$.

Figure below shows how to determine unknown parameter $k$ by simple numeric procedure, which you could also do by hand in few (or dozen) iterations. From this we get $k^\star = 0.0781$ and the terminal velocity is $v_f = 40.57 \text{ m/s}$.

[image: Numeric analysis]

<sup>Figure: Determine unknown parameter $k$ by numeric procedure</sup>

Considering the book you mention is from 1960s, I somehow feel that the author's original intention was not to do numeric simulations to solve this problem. As far as I know there is no analytical method to solve roots of "quadratic plus exponential" equations

$$c y^2 + y + 1 - e^y = 0$$

where $c = \frac{x_f}{g t_f^2}$ and $y = -t_f k$.

---

If you are actually trying to calculate the velocity when acceleration drops to zero

$$v_t = \lim_{t \to \infty} v(t) = \frac{g}{k}$$

the situation is not much different

$$v_t = \frac{g x_f}{g t_f - v_f}$$

because $v_f$ is also unknown and cannot be solved without knowing $k$. Note that knowing only $m$ or only $b$ would not help much because its their ratio is what it matters. However, no numeric procedure would be needed if velocity $v_f$ were known in addition to $x_f$ and $t_f$.

Comment: Thanks, I marked this one since I just can't see another way of doing it. Expanding to approximate looks like it will take a lot of terms to get close. I graphed them and found the same thing you did. Like I mentioned in the OP, I've run into a handful of problems with weird issues like this. A new edition may have fixed this, but it never got one. It's a great book though.

Comment: @Cynewulfa To the best of my knowledge, there is no analytical method to solve roots of a combined quadratic-exponential function. If you do manage to find analytical solution, please come back here and post it :) I will definitely check the book!

Comment: Oops, actually I got the same value of $k$ but I got 124 m/s for the terminal speed. That sort of lines up with the 137 m/s I got doing a short expansion.

Comment: @Cynewulfa Please check your calculations again. The terminal velocity without any drag would be $v_f = \sqrt{2 g x_f}$ which gives $46 \text{ m/s}$.

Comment: That is just how fast it would be moving after being dropped and traveling the given distance. I didn't interpret the problem as saying that it was dropped from a distance of 108 m, only that it travels that far in five seconds. If there's no drag, there is no limiting speed.

Edit: To clarify, what I did was just put $k$ back into the general analytic expression for the terminal speed, so I had $v_\mathrm{T} = \frac{g}{k}$.

Comment: Assume situation with no drag. The work-energy theorem says $\Delta K = W$, where $\Delta K = K_f - K_i$. Since body falls from rest then $K_i = 0$ and $K_f = \frac{1}{2} m v_f^2$. The work is only due to gravitational force, hence $W = mg \Delta x$. From this it follows that velocity after falling distance $\Delta x$ is $v_f = \sqrt{2 g \Delta x}$. I never assumed the body will stop falling, it is velocity after travelling distance $\Delta x$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134659/discussion-between-cynewulfa-and-marko-gulin).

Answer (score -1):

Since you know x=108m and t=5s you can evaluate for b/m and than find v. So you had the solution almost.